# Run Time Error: No Such Column

Tags: java, android, sqlite

When querying for an entry in the table of my database file, a runtime error is thrown indicating that the column queried for does not exist despite the fact that I created it. The following is a screen capture of the Logcat output of my table definition. What is causing the problem?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/PN8m6.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1biZ.png

Comment: Have you cross check your table by using apps like SQLite manager?

Comment: No, I have not done that and am not aware of what help it would offer. However, perhaps I should mention that I'm not using an auto-generated key ("id") to query the database but am using the user's username (I want the user to log in using their username and password).

Comment: Please show the query you are firing for fetching the required data and the error you are getting.

Comment: "what help it would offer" use the apps to crosschecking the column  name is same like your code

Comment: The following is a screen capture that shows the method through which I query my database. http://i.stack.imgur.com/o1biZ.png

Answer (score 0):

GO to DDMS -> File Explorer ->data ->data -> your app package -> database -> your SQLite database, pull it and check if the column does actually exists or not